# Inject an EJB in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

I've defined an **EJB** (by using **Java EE API 7**) as follows:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class Foo {

    @Inject
    private Boo boo;

    public void doFoo(Collection<Object> c) {
        boo.doSomething(c);
    }

}
```

And:

```
@Named
@RequestScope
public class Boo() {

    public void doSomething(Collection<Object> c){
        // Do something...
    }

}
```

Is it possible to inject an instance of `Foo` class as EJB in **Spring**? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an injection interceptor.

> For EJB 3 Session Beans and Message-Driven Beans, Spring provides a
>   convenient interceptor that resolves Spring 2.5's @Autowired
>   annotation in the EJB component class:
>   org.springframework.ejb.interceptor.SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.
>   This interceptor can be applied through an `@Interceptors`
>   annotation in the EJB component class, or through an
>   interceptor-binding XML element in the EJB deployment descriptor.

Code example:

```
@Stateless
@Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)
public class Foo { 

    @Autowired
    private Boo boo;

}
```

For more info, the reference [18.3.2. EJB 3 injection interceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/ejb.html)

If you need to access the EJB from the spring, you can define the bean like the example below in your spring-context.xml configuration

```
<jee:local-slsb id="myComponent" jndi-name="ejb/fooBean"
      business-interface="com.Foo"/>
```

You can have more info about it in the section *18.2.2. Accessing local SLSBs* of the refence above.

Comment: Thus, I cannot completely separate the two frameworks (injecting a pure EJB).

Comment: To be clear, I've a "pure" Java EE project that defines an EJB (the Foo class); it is deployed as jar. For some reasons, I'd like to wire this EJB into a Spring Application.

Comment: just updated my answer on how to access ejb from spring

Comment: Mmm, I'm sorry to bother you, but what is the "jndi-name" definition?

Comment: it is the name of your EJB, as you are using annotation it might be the full package name + class: com.package.Foo... you can also check the name of the ejb when you start the app, it lists the name in the console

Answer (score -1):

I understand you question as: you have problem to inject a request scoped bean into another using spring.
so try this:

```
<bean id="boo" class="Boo" scope="request">
  <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>

<bean id="foo" class="Foo">
  <property name="boo" ref="Boo" />
</bean>
```